# How to list files by permissions

Tags: command-line

In ubuntu we can see a list of files with permissions, simply using the command`ls -l`. But can I add the filter in this case? For example, a list of all files that are permission set to read only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://superuser.com/a/396516/959374

> `ls` doesn't provide this – it's typically used for just tweaking
>   display options. What you can do instead involves using
>   [**`find`**](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Mode-Bits). For example:
>
> ```
> find . -perm -g+s
> ```
>
> To mimic `ls`'s behavior of only listing files in the current
>   directors, use the `-maxdepth 1` option.
>
> The possible combinations are endless. Refer to the `find` help linked
>   above for more examples and the syntax differences in using `-` or `/`
>   before the *mode*, also with respect to `/` being a GNU-only extension
>   and `+` being used in BSD-style `find`.

---

https://superuser.com/a/396516/959374

> `ls` does not directly support sorting by permissions, but you can
>   combine it with the sort command:
>
> ```
> ls -l | sort
> ```
>
> You can use the `-k` option to sort to start matching from a specific
>   character, the format is `-k FIELD.CHAR`, the permissions are the
>   first field in the `ls` output. So e.g. `-k 1.2` will start from the
>   second character of the permission string, which will ignore any
>   directory / device / link etc. flag, or `-k 1.5` for sorting by group
>   permissions.
>
> If you don't want the additional output of `ls -l`, you can remove it
>   with awk:
>
> ```
>  ls -l | sort | awk '{ print $1, $NF}'
> ```
>
> This will print only the first field (the permissions) and the last
>   one (the filename).